# Jquery's $.get call does not return data in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a simple code as follows which make a get call to a django backend to retrieve some string. However, the success function displays an empty string in Google Chrome. In Internet Explorer, the expected string is display.

```
$.get(url, function(data) {alert(data);} );
```

Django class:

```
def lookup(request):
    message= "looking up"
    print message
    return HttpResponse("isss",mimetype="application/text")
```

The Ajax is definitely successful in Chrome so I dont understand why it works in IE and not in Chrome? Could it be some security issue in Chrome?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What does your `url` variable look like?

Comment: /inv/lookup/. And it is mapped to a function in the urls.py file (as required by django)

Comment: please format your question, use ctrl-k or 4 space indent or 101010 button to format code

Comment: Check for errors and suss out the response in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: No errors. I put a breakpoint on the alert statement in the success function but the variable data in empty per the debugger...

Comment: Have you tried it with a MIME type that's less wrong than "application/text"?  Like, maybe "text/plain"?

Comment: Yes, doesn't make a difference...

Comment: Is the page you're running this from `file://` by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Your content type on your request should read 'text/plain'. This is the only part of your problem that would probably be browser based.

In addition, if your not already testing your ajax pieces in FireBug helps quite a lot. I am willing to bet FireBug would have showed you the full request/response.

Comment: Except there's no full-Firebug plugin for Chrome :)

The dev tools are good enough though.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using it in Chrome. Even if it's only happening in a single browser it's often worthwhile to view it in firebug anyway. Dev tools are fine too though.